# Rollback Sqlite database in Firemonkey Multi device project

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, rollback, delphi-10-seattle

How can I rollback my SQLite database after doing a few queries on my iOS/Android device within a Delphi 10 firemonkey multi device project?

I create my database queries using TFDQuery.

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: @CL. No, I am not at the moment

Comment: Well, the [do](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: @CL. So start with "Begin Transaction" then do queries then rollback? And if i do want to commit then commit at the end instead of rollback?

Comment: @CL. Because when I try this I get the message cannot start a transaction within a transaction

Comment: @CL. I've tried to execute the query using DB Browser for Sqlite. I'll try to do it with code. Maybe then it will work fine.

Comment: @CL. It does work when I do it in code! It only has to be all in 1 query that I execute though. If you post your answer ill accept it!

Comment: I don't know what code you used before, and what you changed. You have to write the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TData.RollbackTest;
var
  FD: TFDQuery;
begin
  FD := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FD.Connection := fConnection;
  FD.SQL.Add := 'BEGIN;'
  FD.SQL.Add := 'CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);'
  FD.SQL.Add := 'ROLLBACK;'
  FD.Prepare;
  FD.ExecSQL;
  FD.Free;
end;
```